# XSLT: counting specific nodes based on multiple criteria

Tags: xslt

I have some XML which I would like to transform into a report showing counts on the number of nodes matching a specific criteria within a date period.

Example xml below. I am trying to show a count of nodes based on Status within a date range.

I can match based on date range but I am having trouble showing the status count within that range. Any pointers appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <List>
     <Item>
       <Value name="Status">Open</Value>    
       <Value name="Date">2012-09-01</Value>
       <Value name="Name">Item 1</Value>
     </Item>
     <Item>
       <Value name="Status">Open</Value> 
       <Value name="Date">2012-10-15</Value>
       <Value name="Name">Item 2</Value>
     </Item>
     <Item>
       <Value name="Status">Open</Value> 
       <Value name="Date">2012-10-15</Value>
       <Value name="Name">Item 3</Value>
     </Item>
     <Item>
       <Value name="Status">Pending</Value> 
       <Value name="Date">2012-10-20</Value>
       <Value name="Name">Item 4</Value>
     </Item>
     <Item>
       <Value name="Status">Closed</Value>
       <Value name="Date">2012-10-30</Value>
       <Value name="Name">Item 5</Value>
     </Item>
    </List>
```

Example output would be:-

```
   Status         2012-10-01 - 2012-10-31
   Open           2
   Closed         1
   Pending        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pStartDate" select="20121001"/>
 <xsl:param name="pEndDate" select="20121031"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vInRange" select=
    "/*/*[translate(Value[@name='Date'],'-','') >= $pStartDate
         and
          $pEndDate >= translate(Value[@name='Date'],'-','')
         ]"/>
     Open      <xsl:value-of select="count($vInRange[Value[@name='Status']='Open'])"/>
     Closed    <xsl:value-of select="count($vInRange[Value[@name='Status']='Closed'])"/>
     Pending   <xsl:value-of select="count($vInRange[Value[@name='Status']='Pending'])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <Value name="Status">Open</Value>
        <Value name="Date">2012-09-01</Value>
        <Value name="Name">Item 1</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Value name="Status">Open</Value>
        <Value name="Date">2012-10-15</Value>
        <Value name="Name">Item 2</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Value name="Status">Open</Value>
        <Value name="Date">2012-10-15</Value>
        <Value name="Name">Item 3</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Value name="Status">Pending</Value>
        <Value name="Date">2012-10-20</Value>
        <Value name="Name">Item 4</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Value name="Status">Closed</Value>
        <Value name="Date">2012-10-30</Value>
        <Value name="Name">Item 5</Value>
    </Item>
</List>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
 Open      2
 Closed    1
 Pending   1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dimitre Novatchev